# Elasticsearch date histogram: calculate histogram 'field' from start and stop date?

Tags: date, elasticsearch, histogram

I'd like to plot the number of car trips ongoing on a particular day, every day for the last week.  I know the start time and end time of the trips - the trips can last less than a day, or more than a day.  Ultimately, I will allow the user to set the interval size (i.e. from every day, to every two days) and the date range (i.e. from the last week, to the last two weeks).

It looks like date histogram agreggation might help, but it appears to, in addition to the interval size, take a single date field from which to agreggate into buckets.  In my case, as I only have the start and end times, I'd need some way for the histogram agreggator to calculate, based on start and end times, whether a given trip fits into a given interval bucket.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you share some sample documents and the mapping you're using?

Comment: @Val, all that matters here are two fields in each document:  start_time and end_time, both of type date.  Does that clarify the issue?

Comment: May I ask what version of ES you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern

```
{
  "size": "0",
  "aggs": {
    "articles_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "MyDateField",
        "interval": "1d"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "MyDateField" : {
                        "gte" : "2015-11-01T00:00:00.00",
                        "lte" : "2015-12-01T00:00:00.00"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will aggregate with day buckets for the month of November. If you want buckets of 2 days just change "1d" to "2d"

Comment: What is "MyDateField"?  if that is some field that is supposed to explicitly exist in the documents, then it won't work for me because my documents have a start time (or date) and an end time (or date).

Comment: I think you have two options. One is to include a list of days in the indexed document and then aggregate by values in that list. Obviously this won´t help looking back at already indexed data without reindexing it. Two - Perform a search returning only the document id, start and end dates and perform an aggregation in your application. May be scripting has the answer but I have little experience in that area so can´t suggest anything.